# How to retrieve data of nested class instance from parent class instance in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to modeling a class at school, and I end up with something like this:

```
public class Class
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public Teacher ClassTeacher { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Teacher class:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }  
}
```

When I use scaffolding, migrate and update the database, this is the structure Entity Framework built for me:

```
dbo.Class:
ID: int
ClassTeacherID: int
Grade: int

dbo.Teacher:
ID: int
Birthday: datetime2(7)
FirstName: nvarchar(MAX)
LastName: nvarchar(MAX)
```

I want to display the `Teacher`'s `FirstName` in `Views\Classes\Details.cshtml`, but the `Model.ClassTeacher` is `null`, even after I created a `Teacher` instance in the database and set `ClassTeacherID` to the newly created `Teacher`'s `ID`.

Looking for your helps.

**EDIT**

*ClassesController.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class ClassesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly WebApplication1Context _context;

        public ClassesController(WebApplication1Context context)
        {
            _context = context;    
        }

        // GET: Classes
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Class.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Classes/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var @class = await _context.Class
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (@class == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(@class);
        }

        // GET: Classes/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Classes/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,Grade")] Class @class)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(@class);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(@class);
        }

        // GET: Classes/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var @class = await _context.Class.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (@class == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(@class);
        }

        // POST: Classes/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Grade")] Class @class)
        {
            if (id != @class.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(@class);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ClassExists(@class.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(@class);
        }

        // GET: Classes/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var @class = await _context.Class
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (@class == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(@class);
        }

        // POST: Classes/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var @class = await _context.Class.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            _context.Class.Remove(@class);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        private bool ClassExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Class.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

*TeachersController.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class TeachersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly WebApplication1Context _context;

        public TeachersController(WebApplication1Context context)
        {
            _context = context;    
        }

        // GET: Teachers
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Teacher.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Teachers/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var teacher = await _context.Teacher
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (teacher == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(teacher);
        }

        // GET: Teachers/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Teachers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,FirstName,LastName,Birthday")] Teacher teacher)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(teacher);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(teacher);
        }

        // GET: Teachers/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var teacher = await _context.Teacher.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (teacher == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(teacher);
        }

        // POST: Teachers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,FirstName,LastName,Birthday")] Teacher teacher)
        {
            if (id != teacher.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(teacher);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!TeacherExists(teacher.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(teacher);
        }

        // GET: Teachers/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var teacher = await _context.Teacher
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (teacher == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(teacher);
        }

        // POST: Teachers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var teacher = await _context.Teacher.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            _context.Teacher.Remove(teacher);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        private bool TeacherExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Teacher.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how your controller action code looks like?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad actually I didn't edit any of these codes, they are created automatically by VS2017.

Comment: you need to show relevant code where you populate the model before passing to view, otherwise there is no way for any of us to point you where you have done mistake if any

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the question has been written, but you should try to **Include** the object reference you want.

```
var @class = await _context.Class.Include("Teacher")
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

Include will get the dependent object and put it back in your Class model.
You can chain the Include directives if you have different referenced objects.

Note : You will have to add :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

on top of your code to allow Include to work.